# Expresiones Regulares - String con más de una palabra

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Necesito encontrar todas las empresas donde el string, empiece y acabe por vocal. Tengo el siguiente listado:

```
{'AV Stores, Co.',
 'Alpha Cognac',
 'Amica Models & Co.',
 "Anna's Decorations, Ltd",
 'Atelier graphique',
 'Australian Collectables, Ltd',
 'Australian Collectors, Co.',
 'Australian Gift Network, Co',
 'Auto Assoc. & Cie.',
 'Auto Canal Petit',
 'Auto-Moto Classics Inc.',
 'Enaco Distributors',
 'Euro Shopping Channel',
 'Iberia Gift Imports, Corp.',
 'Online Diecast Creations Co.',
 'Online Mini Collectables',
 'Osaka Souveniers Co.',
 'Oulu Toy Supplies, Inc.',
 'UK Collectables, Ltd.'}
```

El listado de empresas que empiezan por vocal lo he obtenido con el siguinte código:

```
exp = r"^[AEIOU]"
empreses = [n for n in df['CUSTOMERNAME'] if re.search(exp,n) is not None]
set(empreses)
```

La variable `exp` es mi patrón de búsqueda. Encuentro todas las palabras que empiecen por vocal y luego hago un `set` para crear un lista sin duplicados. En esta lista no deberían aparecer empresas como Alpha Cognac o AV Stores, Co. ya que no acaban en vocal pero si Atelier graphique. Cómo consigo buscar en palabras posteriores a la primera?

Comment: ¿qué es lo que debe terminar en vocal? La segunda palabra? La última palabra antes de la coma? (ej:  "Atelier Graphique, Co.") ¿La última palabra de la cadena? (Ej: "Australian Girft Network, Co") ¿Y el punto final que a veces aparece? ¿Debe ser eliminado? (Ej: "Osaka Souvernirs Co." cuenta como que termina en vocal?

Comment: El punto final forma parte de la palabra. Ej: "Osaka Souvernirs Co." no debe considerarse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si se trata simplemente de verificar que cada una de las cadenas tenga vocal como primer y último carácter, puedes usar en la expresión regular algo como `^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$` pues el `^` representa el inicio de la cadena, el `$` representa el final, y el `.*` capturará cualquier secuencia de caracteres.

Convendrá usar el flag `IGNORECASE` para que valgan mayúsculas y minúsculas:

```
exp = re.compile(r"^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$", re.IGNORECASE)
empreses = set(n for n in df['CUSTOMERNAME'] if re.match(exp,n))
```

Produce el conjunto:

```
{'Atelier graphique', 'Australian Gift Network, Co'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Entendemos que las partes como "Corp.", "Inc.", "Co." y otras similares no son realmente parte del nombre de la empresa, por lo que hay que excluirlas antes de analizar lo que queda. Ponemos estos términos en una lista de exclusión

```
excluir = ["Ltd", "Co", "Inc", "Cie", "s"]
```

También definimos dos patrones que calzan con vocales al principio y al final de una palabra

```
vocal_ini = "^[aeiou]"
vocal_fin = "[aeiou]$"
```

Lo que nos queda es dividir el nombre de la empresa en sus partes, eliminar los términos a excluir y luego analizar la primera y la última palabra a ver si calzan con los patrones deseados. Para facilitar el análisis, convertimos los nombres a minúsculas para hacer el pattern matching

```
nombres_seleccionados = []
for empresa in empresas:
    nombres = [nombre for nombre in re.findall("\w+", empresa) if nombre not in excluir]
    if re.search(vocal_ini, nombres[0].lower()) and re.search(vocal_fin, nombres[-1].lower()):
        nombres_seleccionados.append(empresa)
```

**Demo**

Agregue un par de nombres que cumplen la condición a la lista

```
import re

empresas = ['AV Stores, Co.',
 'Alpha Cognac',
 'Amica Models & Co.',
 "Anna's Decorations, Ltd",
 'Atelier graphique',
 'Australian Collectables, Ltd',
 'Australian Collectors, Co.',
 'Australian Gift Network, Co',
 'Auto Assoc. & Cie.',
 'Auto Canal Petit',
 'Auto-Moto Classics Inc.',
 'Enaco Distributors',
 'Euro Shopping Channel',
 'Iberia Gift Imports, Corp.',
 'Online Diecast Creations Co.',
 'Online Mini Collectables',
 'Osaka Souveniers Co.',
 'Oulu Toy Supplies, Inc.',
 'UK Collectables, Ltd.',
 'Acme, Inc.',
 'Endesa Generacion Electrica']

excluir = ["Ltd", "Co", "Inc", "Cie", "s"]
vocal_ini = "^[aeiou]"
vocal_fin = "[aeiou]$"

nombres_seleccionados = []
for empresa in empresas:
    nombres = [nombre for nombre in re.findall("\w+", empresa) if nombre not in excluir]
    if re.search(vocal_ini, nombres[0].lower()) and re.search(vocal_fin, nombres[-1].lower()):
        nombres_seleccionados.append(empresa)

print(nombres_seleccionados)
```

produce:

```
['Atelier graphique', 'Acme, Inc.', 'Endesa Generacion Electrica']
```

Answer (score 0):

Si solo quieres detectar las que empiezan y acaban por vocal, puedes hacerlo también de la siguiente manera:

```
voc = lambda x: x.lower() in 'aeiou'
lista = [emp for emp in empresas if voc(emp[0]) and voc(emp[-1])]
```

Lo que hace `voc` es comprobar que lo que le pasemos a la función en minúscula está en `'aeiou'`. Luego solo hay que pasarle esta función a la primera y la última letra de la cadena, si cumple entra en `lista`.

Pasándolo a tu lista de empresas te devolvería:

```
['Australian Gift Network, Co', 'Atelier graphique']
```